# The import jdk.nashorn cannot be resolved

Tags: java, nashorn

I am trying to import a project into my eclipse workspace. When I maven updated the project, this dependency is not getting downloaded.
When I searched online, I found that **jdk.nashorn** is not supported from **java 11** onwards. But I am using  **java 1.8.0_231**, still its not working for me.

The code uses below class from the library.

```
import jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.debug.ObjectSizeCalculator;

ObjectSizeCalculator.getObjectSize(modRespList)
```

***Is there any way to make this code work?***

Comment: Nashorn has been removed from newer Java versions. You must import it as a separate dependency.

Comment: @QuentinC But I am using java 8. Is it not supported in java 8 as well?

Comment: @Abra Code doesn't compile. Getting exception that class cannot be resolved.
 "ObjectSizeCalculator cannot be resolved". 
After I added external jar file `nashorn-0.1.0.2013070801` to the project, the code is compiling.
Doesn't the nashorn library come with jdk 1.8.*?

Comment: Yes, it's indeed included with Java 8 without the need to download a separate dependency. It's still included with Java 11 but deprecated. It has been completely removed afterwards. Your Java version wasn't precised at the time I read your question for the first time, or maybe I missed the info.

Comment: Since you are on Java 8, I have no idea, sorry. You should try to compile your project outside eclipse, to make sure that a possibly newer Java version used internally by eclipse won't interfere.

Comment: @QuentinC Ok. Thank you. I will try and check with another IDE.

Comment: Not facing this issue with Intellij. Not sure why the issue with Eclipse.

Comment: OK, so it's an eclipse specific issue. Maybe you should check the configuration of your project. You are probably set in a more recent version of Java by default. Eclipse doesn't always automatically take the right version based on  what's specified in pom.xml.

Comment: Yeah. Java version of the project is set to 1.8 in pom.xml. It seems like an Eclipse issue.